# Shakambhari Navrathri

Tags: devi, durga, shakti, kali, navrathri

[image]I had thought there were four Navrathri every year, the two gupt ones then the two well-known ones in spring/fall. These are the ones I was observing as starting down devi-bhakti path.

However now finding out about Paush/Shakambhari Navrathri also, which is celebrated in many places in Dec/January. So for example, in this year it was celebrated first week January 2022.

So perhaps there are five Navrathri celebrated each year ?

Are there any others I still don’t know about ?

Shakambhari Devi is form of Shakti/Durga/Kali, had heard of the stories about her a few years ago but didn’t realize she had her own Navrathri too, which is wonderful btw :D

Comment: Ok looking up more and there are lots of Hindu websites, youtube videos, news stories etc of people observing Shakambari Navrathri. How did I know not about this festival before ?? This is the fifth Navrathri I am finding out about. Seems like a very good festival for vegan bhakts too :D

Comment: As devi Bhagwatam says Shakambhari devi let waters to fell frm her 100 eyes for 9 days and 9 nights that's what is the reason of Shakambhari Navaratri

Comment: @Chamundadas Thx ! The next Shakambhari Navrathri is Dec 30th 2022 till January 6th 2023, I will observe :D